# preg_match which returns the content of regex match rather than a true or false value

Tags: php, regex

I wish for a function like `preg_match`, but which returns the content of regex match rather than a true or false value

```
$warehouse = preg_match( '/^[0-9]+/', $warehouse );
```

This would return true or false, but I want an equivalent function which would return the contents of the regex match.

So in the case of `$warehouse = 10+ at supplier`,
then `function( '/^[0-9]+/', $warehouse );` would return `10`.

Comment: [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is what you want. Add the _$matches_ parameter. See the manual for all the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), you'll see `preg_match` can take a third parameter, `$matches`, into which the matched strings are placed. With no groups in your regex, the entire matched string will be in `$matches[0]`. For example:

```
$warehouse = '354-Sydney';
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+/', $warehouse, $matches)) {
     echo $matches[0];
}
```

Output:

```
354
```